# 'esnext.array' compiler option doesn't enable access to Array.prototype.flat()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make my Angular 2 app compile when using JavaScript array experimental features like [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

I've added `esnext.array` option to `tsconfig.json`, so the `lib` section looks like this:

```
"lib": [
    "es2017",
    "esnext.array",
    "dom"
],
```

I've checked [`lib.esnext.array.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.esnext.array.d.ts) file and it indeed contains definitions for the `flat()` method.

But despite this, I'm getting a compilation error:

> ERROR in src/app/services/service.ts(286,22): error TS2339: Property
>   'flat' does not exist on type 'ReadonlyMap[]'.

**UPDATE 1:**
I've checked `esnext` option which results in the same error.

Also, I've checked that Angular CLI picks up the `lib`options by typing something non-existent like `esnext.array.dfgdfg`.

**UPDATE 2:**
To exclude a possibility that it's something wrong with the TypeScript version 2.9.2 or Angular toolchain, I've created a simple project with pure TypeScript:

```
// greeter.ts
function greeter(persons: string[]) {
    return "Hello, " + persons.flat().join();
}

var user: string[] = ["Jane User"];

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "esnext.array",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And tried to compile it with TypsScript 2.9.2, the current latest 3.0.1 and `typescript@next`, but I always get the same error:

> greeter.ts:2:32 - error TS2339: Property 'flat' does not exist on type
>   'string[]'.
>
> 2     return "Hello, " + persons.flat().join();
>                                    ~~~~

Could somebody explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: I am only making a guess, but have you tried `"esnext"` instead of `"esnext.array"`?

Comment: It works for me using plain `tsc` without Angular.  Maybe stick a deliberately invalid compiler option in your `tsconfig.json` to test whether it is even being used?

Comment: @cgTag: Just tried `esnext`, the error is the same.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen: Just tried something like `esnext.array.dfgdfg` which resulted in compiler complaining about wrong `lib` option, so it seems Angular CLI correctly passes it to `tsc`. Could you let me know which version of TypeSctipt have you tried, please? Maybe this is the key. Mine is 2.9.2, since it's the last currently supported by Angular.

Comment: Are you sure `flat` is part of the `ReadonlyMap` type definition for `esnext`? When I read the specs for `flat` it appears to be only for arrays.

Comment: @cgTag: I'm calling `flat()` on a `ReadonlyMap[]` variable (an array of `ReadonlyMap`s) as it's in the compiler error above. So it should be there.

Comment: oh I see. I missed that it was an array.

Comment: On the simple project, I get the error with TypeScript 2.9.2 and no error with TypeScript 3.0.1.  Perhaps run `tsc --version` and make sure you're using the version you think you are?  Then if you're on Linux, try running `strace -e trace=file tsc ...` and make sure tsc is loading the correct `lib.esnext.array.d.ts` file.

Comment: FTR, looks like this has been resolved at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26361 .

Answer (score 0):

In older TypeScript versions, `flat()` has been called `flatten()`. So if you're stuck with those TS versions, you might try using `flatten()` instead.